# Can I parse raw style element in Kramdown?

Tags: markdown, kramdown

i want to parse raw style element in markdown file.

but Kramdown change spaces to `&nbsp` like below.

from

```
<style markdown="0">
.sample {
    color :red !important;
}
</style>
```

to

```
<style>
.sample&nbsp;{
    color&nbsp;:red&nbsp;!important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I just attempted to replicate this bug and was unsuccessful, kramdown did not insert any non-breaking spaces and behaved as expected. Accordingly, this does not appear to be an issue with kramdown. Are you using kramdown by itself or using it through some other program?

Comment: I use kramdown with Jykell.
is this a Jykell's issue?

Comment: Sure looks like it. Vanilla kramdown parses this correctly.